# How do I increase div height with child content?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the white background poking out around the title, also poke out to the rest of the content.
I have tried overflow, clear, min-height max-height, *, everything I can think of.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ventura County CEC</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global.css">

    <style type="text/css">
        html
        {
            height: 100%;
        }
        body
        {
            min-height: 100%;
        }
        #courseContainer
        {
            width: 960px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            position: relative;
            margin: 0 auto;
            height: *;
            /*min-height: 1610px;*/
            padding-left: 15px;
            padding-right: 15px;
        }

        #courses
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 221px;
            height: *;
            width: 960px;
            border: 1px #cccccc dotted;
            border-radius: 4px;
            /*height: -moz-calc(* + 3px);
            height: -webkit-calc(* + 3px);
            height: -o-calc(* + 3px);
            height: calc(* + 3px);*/
            padding-bottom: 3px;
            background: #ffffff;
        }

        /*#superCourses
        {
            background: #ffffff;
            width: 960px;
            height: *;
        }*/

        .course
        {
            position: relative;
            height: 120px;
            width: 952px;
            margin-top: 3px;
            margin-left: 3px;
            border: 1px #cccccc dotted;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }

        .course_title
        {
            position: absolute;
            left: 5px;
            width: 150px;
            height: 120px;
            line-height: 100px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .titleAlign
        {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
            line-height: normal;
        }

        .course_description
        {

            position: absolute;
            left: 150px;
            top: 10px;
            bottom: 10px;
            width: 340px;
            height: 100px;
            overflow: auto;
            z-index: 5;


        }

        .course_pics
        {

            position: absolute;
            left: 450px;
            height: 110px;
            width: 100px;
            margin-top: 5px;

        }

        .picture
        {

            position: absolute;
            height: 110px;
            width: 250px;

        }

        .course_ment_loc
        {
            position: absolute;
            right: 5px;
            top: 10px;
            width: 200px;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            height: 110px;
        }

        .teacher
        {
            top: 0px;
        }

        .school
        {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="courseContainer">

        <?php include 'title.php';?>
        <div id="superCourses">
            <div id="courses">

                <div id="list">
                    <?php include 'CECCourses/courseTemplate.php';?>
                    <?php include 'CECCourses/courseTemplate.php';?>
                    <?php include 'CECCourses/courseTemplate.php';?>
                    <?php include 'CECCourses/courseTemplate.php';?>
                    <?php include 'CECCourses/courseTemplate.php';?>
                    <?php include 'CECCourses/courseTemplate.php';?>
                    <?php include 'CECCourses/courseTemplate.php';?>
                    <?php include 'CECCourses/courseTemplate.php';?>
                    <?php include 'CECCourses/courseTemplate.php';?>
                    <?php include 'CECCourses/courseTemplate.php';?>
                    <?php include 'CECCourses/courseTemplate.php';?>
                    <?php include 'CECCourses/courseTemplate.php';?>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: height: *; is not valid CSS.

Comment: Why are you using absolute positioning? If you don't know, you probably shouldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `#courses` div is absolutely positioned, which is why your background does not envelop the element.

If you remove the `position: absolute;` from this element it will resolve your issue and the background will extend the full height. Note that position style for #courses is attributed twice: once in your global.css and once on courses.php.

---

**Edit:**

If the positioning on `#courses` is used on other pages and global.css needs to remain as-is, just change the courses.php styles to change #courses to be relatively positioned:

```
#courses
{
    position: relative;
    top: 221px;
    height: *;
    width: 960px;
    border: 1px #cccccc dotted;
    border-radius: 4px;
    /*height: -moz-calc(* + 3px);
    height: -webkit-calc(* + 3px);
    height: -o-calc(* + 3px);
    height: calc(* + 3px);*/
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem was both the courses id was in the local and global CSS. Changed the name of the div, and removed the position attribute.
Thank you.

Comment: @Sodra Great, I'm glad you sorted this. And as a Canadian I agree, french toast _is_ delicious with syrup.